# Multi-level json to SQL outputs per element instead of per row

Tags: sql, json, powershell, type-conversion

I'm using the Microsoft 365 Defender API to receive all recent events/incidents.

I get a json file as following: [link to example json](https://github.com/sander110419/Problems/blob/main/example.json)

And use following script to try and convert this for easy import to an SQL server:
(Echoes only as test)

```
# Send the request and get the results.
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ErrorAction Stop

# Extract the incidents from the results.
$alerts = ($response | ConvertFrom-Json)
$devices = ($response | ConvertFrom-Json ).value.alerts.devices
$entities = ($response | ConvertFrom-Json ).value.alerts.entities

Foreach($row in $alerts){
$IncidentID = $alerts.value.incidentID
$Createdtime = $alerts.value.creationTime
$Status = $alerts.value.status
$Severity = $alerts.value.severity
$Classification = $alerts.value.classification
$IncidentName = $alerts.value.incidentName
$URL = $alerts.incidentUri
$Klant = $afkorting
$Username = $entities.accountname
$device = $devices.deviceDnsName

echo $IncidentID
echo $Createdtime
echo $Status
echo $Severity
echo $Classification
echo $IncidentName
echo $URL
echo $Klant
echo $Username
echo $device
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "SQL.domain.local\MSQL2016" -Database "private" -Username private -Password 'private' -Query "INSERT Into dbo.private ( [IncidentID], [Createdtime], [Status], [Severity], [Classification], [IncidentName], [URL], [Klant], [Username], [device]) VALUES ('$IncidentID', '$Createdtime', '$Status', '$Severity', '$Classification', '$IncidentName', '$URL', '$Klant', '$Username', '$device')"
}
```

However, the output in case of 3 incidents looks like:

IncidentID
IncidentID
IncidentID
Createdtime
Createdtime
Createdtime
Status
Status
Status

So grouped by element instead of grouped by IncidentID.

I can't find a way to get the output like:

> IncidentID
> Createdtime
> Status
> Severity
> Classification
> IncidentName
> URL
> Klant
> Username
> device

I "solved" this with an intermediary step exporting to CSV's and merging them and piping those to SQL for now, but that's too inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Move resolution of `$devices` and `$entities` into the loop, then *use the iterator variable `$row`* instead of referencing *all* `$alerts` inside the loop body:

```
# Send the request and get the results.
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Method Get -Uri $url -Headers $headers -ErrorAction Stop

# Extract the incidents from the results.
$alerts = ($response | ConvertFrom-Json)

foreach($row in $alerts){
  $IncidentID     = $row.value.incidentID
  $Createdtime    = $row.value.creationTime
  $Status         = $row.value.status
  $Severity       = $row.value.severity
  $Classification = $row.value.classification
  $IncidentName   = $row.value.incidentName
  $URL            = $row.incidentUri
  $Klant          = $afkorting              # where does `$afkorting` come from?
  $Username       = $row.value.entities.accountname
  $device         = $row.value.devices.deviceDnsName

  # Insert into SQL Server here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this has the same problem, the SQL table now shows on row 1 in column IncidentID: `23 15 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 13 14`  AKA all values in 1 row instead of 1 row per ID. $afkorting is defined before the $response and has a customer ID in it.

Comment: @Sander Then the sample JSON you linked to is incomplete (a parent level property `value` seems to have been omitted at least?), please post an actual sample

Comment: I editted the original json to the actual one (removing personal info)
[link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sander110419/Problems/main/example.json)